# Document count aggregation via query in Elasticsearch (like facet.query in solr)

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, faceted-search, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have a main query and i need the number of matches for a couple of sub-queries.
In solr words I need a [facet.query](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceting#Faceting-Thefacet.queryParameter). What I am missing is a simple `doc_count` aggregation like the [value_count aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-valuecount-aggregation.html).

Any suggestions?

I found two possible solutions which I do not like:

1. Use [filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) with [value_count](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-valuecount-aggregation.html) metric on `_id`:

example:

```
GET _search
{
    "query": {
        "match_main": {}
    },
    "aggs": {
            "facetvalue1": {
                "filter": {
                     "bool": { 
                    "should": [
                      {"match": { "name": "fred" }},
                      {"term": { "lastname": "krueger" }}
                     ]
                     }
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "count": {
                        "value_count": {
                            "field": "_id"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "facetvalue2": {
                "filter": {
                      "term": { "name": "freddy" }
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "count": {
                        "value_count": {
                            "field": "_id"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

2. Use [Multi Search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-multi-search.html)

example:

```
GET _msearch
{"index":"myindex"}
{"query":{"match_main": {}}}
{"index":"myindex"}
{"size": 0, "query":{"match_main": {}}, "filter": {"bool": {"should":[{"match": { "name": "fred" }},{"term": { "lastname": "krueger" }}]}}}
{"index":"myindex"}
{"size": 0, "query":{"match_main": {}},"filter": {"term": { "name": "freddy" }}}
```

I see that solution 2 is faster but imagine `match_main` as complex query!
So I would prefer solution 1 if there would be an `doc_count:{}` instead of `value_count:{"field":"_id"}`.

But back to my basic question: what is the counterpart of the solr `facet.query` in elasticsearch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`filters aggregation`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html) for this. Note the additional `s`, that is different from the `filter` aggregation you already mentioned.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "values": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "value1": {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "match": {
                    "name": "fred"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "term": {
                    "lastname": "krueger"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "value2": {
            "term": {
              "name": "freddy"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will return something like

```
"aggregations": {
  "values": {
    "buckets": {
      "value1": {
        "doc_count": 4
      },
      "value2": {
        "doc_count": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: As a general note, you don't have to use a metric aggregation on your bucket aggregations. If you don't provide any subaggregations, you will just get the document count. In this case, `filters` will provide the buckets, but multiple `filter` aggregations should work as well.

Comment: To expand on your note: If you're using top level **Metrics Aggregations** (which don't show the document count as the **Bucket Aggregations** do), but you need the document count, you can embed your Metrics Aggregations inside a [filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) Bucket Aggregation. That way you get the document count even though you're not using buckets. Example: `filter: { match_all: {} }, aggs: { sum: { ... }}`. BTW: don't use `hits.total.value`, it's limited to 10K